# Flask: Programa pede para inserir ID, porém este deveria ser gerado automaticamente

Tags: python, crud, flask, sqlalchemy

Estou utilizando o framework flask para fazer um CRUD de um esquema de bancos. Mapeei da seguinte maneira com o Flask-SQLAlchemy:

```
class Banco(db.Model): #Mapeamento
__tablename__ = 'banco'

id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True)
nome = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
numero = db.Column(db.Text)
ispb = db.Column(db.Integer)
agencia = db.relationship('Agencia',backref='banco',lazy=True)

def __init__(self, id,nome,numero,ispb):
    self.id = id
    self.nome = nome
    self.numero = numero
    self.ispb = ispb
```

Dessa forma, eu quero justamente gerar o id de forma sequencial. Tal como em banco de dados.
Com isso ao criar o CRUD, utilizo o WTF-Flask para gerar os campos:

```
class AddBancoForm(FlaskForm):
    nome = StringField('nome',validators=[InputRequired(),DataRequired()])
    numero = StringField('numero',validators=[InputRequired(),DataRequired()])
    ispb = IntegerField('ispb',validators=[DataRequired()])
```

Entretanto, quando faço o request desses campos, o programa me pede para inserir o id. Este que deveria ser gerado automaticamente. O que estou fazendo de errado?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você instanciar a classe 'Banco', será necessário informar o id por causa do construtor. Nesse caso, a classe é uma tabela, então não precisa declarar o **init**

```
class Banco(db.Model): 
  __tablename__ = 'tb_banco'   
  id = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False,autoincrement=True)
  nome = db.Column(db.Text,nullable=False)
  numero = db.Column(db.Text)
  ispb = db.Column(db.Integer)
  agencia = db.relationship('Agencia',backref='banco',lazy=True)
```

Agora, quando você precisar criar um registro, basta você chamar a classe informando os parâmetros.

```
new_banco = Banco(nome='vitor', numero='231', ispb=1)  
db.session.add(new_banco)
db.session.commit() #adiciona new_banco ao banco de dados
```

documentação: https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/

Answer (score -3):

A resolução do problema é a seguinte:

- Na função ***init*** ,não deve-se colocar *self.id = id*

  ```
    def __init__(self,nome,numero,ispb):
       self.nome = nome
       self.numero = numero
       self.ispb = ispb
  ```